# Magento 2.1.8 error on MGS builder sale section

Tags: magento2, error

I'm working with MGS frontend builder and i'm getting an console error "require" not defined on sale product section and new product section.
I don't have this bug on my local environment, just on production server.
I deleted cache, reindexed,compiled and deployed and no luck.

This error seems so common. Does anyone have any idea ho to fix it?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. It was another module that has been recently enabled and was rewrithing the functionality for getting the products for the owlcarousel slider.